# React Native Biometrics returns BiometricType as Biometrics

Tags: javascript, react-native, biometrics

I am using react native biometrics package for authentication and when I checked for BiometricType using isSensorAvailable it is returning Biometrics instead of FaceID or TouchID or undefined.

How can I check if face id is enabled in my device.Below is my code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import ReactNativeBiometrics, {BiometryTypes} from 'react-native-biometrics';

const FaceIdLogin = () => {
  const [isFaceIdAvailable, setIsFaceIdAvailable] = useState(false);

  const checkFaceId = async () => {
    const rnBiometrics = new ReactNativeBiometrics();
    rnBiometrics.isSensorAvailable().then(resultObject => {
      const {available, biometryType} = resultObject;

      if (available && biometryType === BiometryTypes.TouchID) {
        console.log('TouchID is supported');
      } else if (available && biometryType === BiometryTypes.FaceID) {
        console.log('FaceID is supported');
      } else if (available && biometryType === BiometryTypes.Biometrics) {
        console.log(BiometryTypes.Biometrics,'Biometrics is supported');
      } else {
        console.log('Biometrics not supported');
      }
    });
  };

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Biometrics.authenticate(
        'Authenticate to login with Face ID',
      );

      if (result.success) {
        // Handle successful authentication
      } else {
        // Handle authentication failure
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {isFaceIdAvailable
          ? 'Face ID is available'
          : 'Face ID is not available'}
      </Text>
      <Button title="Check Face ID availability" onPress={checkFaceId} />
      <Button
        title="Login with Face ID"
        onPress={handleLogin}
        disabled={!isFaceIdAvailable}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default FaceIdLogin;
```